# Where to store user specific settings in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

For example title, database host, ext. And be able to edit it via Form on Site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the database, I guess.

If you want to store settings of various data types and complexity, you could use a NoSQL database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). You could store numbers, strings, arrays, object, etc. in a single collection; in a relational database you would have to serialize arrays and objects or add complexity by having to join tables. And there is a [bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) for MongoDB.

Comment: And where to store DB config to be able edit it on site via form?